# liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3 with default configuration giving null pointer exception

Tags: jboss7.x

I followed all required basic steps to deploy liferay 6.1 with jboss 7.2 properly
But I am getting following error--

```
10:03:32,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "ROOT.war"
10:04:08,447 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[jsp]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:425)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:79) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:576) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:471) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:728) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:243) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:559) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:536) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        eb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:388) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49) [jboss-as-jpa-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]

10:04:09,001 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[jsp]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:94) [util-taglib.jar:]
        at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:39) [util-taglib.jar:]
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:451)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:396)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:79) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:79) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:282) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221) [struts.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:559) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:536) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:314) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:79) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:5989) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:5864) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_22]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_22]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_22]
        at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.doInvoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:88) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.invoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:56) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at $Proxy399.sendError(Unknown Source)  at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.sendError(PortalUtil.java:1671) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:742) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:243) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:559) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:536) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:314) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:79) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:137) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:355) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:314) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:260) [portal-impl.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) [portal-service.jar:]com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:79) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:388) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49) [jboss-as-jpa-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]

10:04:09,607 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 10:04:09,600 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1][error_jsp:394] User ID null
10:04:09,618 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 10:04:09,618 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1][error_jsp:395] Current URL /
10:04:09,619 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 10:04:09,619 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1][error_jsp:396] Referer null
10:04:09,620 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 10:04:09,619 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1][error_jsp:397] Remote address 192.168.3.250
10:04:09,623 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) 10:04:09,621 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1][error_jsp:399] java.lang.NullPointerException
10:04:09,624 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) java.lang.NullPointerException
10:04:09,624 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)      at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:94)
10:04:09,625 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)      at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:39)
10:04:09,625 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)      at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:451
)
```

Please can any one have idea How to resolve this...?

Comment: Post your `portal-ext.properties` file, and please highlight what instructions you followed to deploy.

Comment: my portal-ext.properties contains---
`mail.session.mail.smtp.host=inmail.zycus.com
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
setup.wizard.enabled=false`

Comment: #Steps I followed:
1 extract jboss and liferay-portal-dependencies in com/liferay/portal/main/.
2 Create module.xml and add sqljdbc4 driver in liferay/jboss/modules/com/liferay/portal/main. 
3 enable-welcome-root="false" Insert <configuration> element in web subsystem element. 
4 changing deployment-timeout="900".
5 Add JAAS security domain.
6 setting JAVA_OPTS .
7 adding datasource in standalone.xml.
8 liferay-portal.war into ROOT.war folder.
9 making empty file named ROOT.war.dodeploy. 
10 changing port binding.